# The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'Function'

Tags: flutter, dart

How to fix this?

[image: items]

Measures:

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> measures(BuildContext context) {
  return[
    {"label": S.of(context).distanceTranslate, "icon": "assets/icons/ruler2.png"},
    {"label": S.of(context).distanceTranslate, "icon": "assets/icons/temp2.png"},
    {"label": S.of(context).distanceTranslate, "icon": "assets/icons/paid4.png"},
    {"label": S.of(context).distanceTranslate, "icon": "assets/icons/time2.png"},
    {"label": S.of(context).distanceTranslate, "icon": "assets/icons/binary2.png"},
  ];
}
```

Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`measures` is a function and it returns a value when called.
You need to call it to get it's value. Here is an easy fix:

```
// from this:
measures.map(...).toList();
// to this:
measures(context).map(...).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

`measures` is a function and you're using it as a variable that's cause to issue.
Update your code as below

```
 items: measures(context).map(
                      (e) => BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Image.asset(e['icon']),
                        label: e['label'], 
                      ),
                    ).toList(),
```